# Accessing Webservice API from another PC

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services

I am a complete beginner and made a sample REST Webservice on my PC. I want to call the GET API from another PC, which is connected to my PC via ethernet cable.

I am already able to access the API from another PC through IP address in the URL. For this, I had to **change the binding protocol** as mentioned in this [blog post](https://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer). Basically, I added a line `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58938:192.168.1.42" />` in the file `/{project folder}/.vs/config/applicationhost.config`, where `192.168.1.42` is the IP address of my PC.

**PROBLEM:** Since the web service will run at different customer's PC so, I will not have any information about the IP address. Therefore, I need a solution where I don't need to add the IP address in the`applicationhost.config` file.

Is there a way that I can make a fixed URL with which I can access the web service from any other PC via http (both the PC connected by ethernet cable).

Comment: The application that is calling the web api end point needs a network address to do so. If you are not sure how to get this network address then you need to do some reading on network configurations / setup. You will need to use either a static IP address or a network name that can be resolved by the router or switch to the IP of the host.

Comment: The address is crucial to being able to communicate with a remote PC. By the way, you would need a crossover cable if you're connecting directly via an ethernet cable. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable)

Answer (score 0):

Make the IP of the Clients PC Static lets say to 192.168.1.1 when hosting your server on the Clients PC IIS by giving a PORT no lets say 9000 then you can you use the Web API By calling 192.168.1.1:9000 by this you will be able to access the API.